# Event Receiver deploying to multiple form libreries

Tags: list, infopath, event-receivers, form

I have three infopath form libreries: lib-2015, lib-2015,lib-2016. I inherited an event receiver that has been deployed to 2014, 2015 library, now I am trying to deploy it to 2016 library. Changing listurl attribute in Elements.xml and redeploying this event receiver has absolutely no effect, it just stays with 2014, 2015 libraries even if I completely removed references to it in elements.xml. The whole solution file contains no references to two libraries that it has been deployed to.

How is this possible and what is it that i need to do to deploy this event receiver to 2016 library.

Regards and thanks,

Nemanja